# Stored procedure in logic app outputs splitted xml object

Tags: sql, json, xml, stored-procedures, azure-logic-apps

I wrote a logic app that executes a stored procedure in an on-prem database with the on-prem gateway. In SQL Server Management Studio, I get the result as a complete xml object.

But when I execute that stored procedure in Azure logic apps my result of the same xml object gets split into multiple json objects instead of one json object with the full xml string inside.

In SQL Server Management Studio, I have `FOR XML RAW, Root('<RootName>')` after the SQL select statement.

Why is this, and how do I solve this problem?

Below is an screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar issue by implementing simple Function App to fix the output.

In my case it is a JSON generated by SQL query FOR JSON AUTO, but you should be able to apply the same to XML. The following article mentions that

> [A large result set splits the long JSON string across multiple
>   rows.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server)

I implemented a simple Function App to process the output and consolidate it into single JSON payload.

Here is the code of my Function which is a Generic Webhook function:

```
    public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"ProcessSentimentJson was triggered!");

        string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        JArray array = JArray.Parse(jsonContent);

        List<string> list = array.Select(p => (string)p["JSON_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B"]).ToList();
        foreach (var l in list)
            sb.Append(l);

        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, sb.ToString());
    }
```

Then you can add it to your Logic App, pass the results from the stored proc and use the output in the next activity:

[image]

Happy coding!

Comment: Yeah i was thinking around a similar solution but was hoping to be able to do it without a solution like that but i guess that's how i will have to do it. I'll test around with something similar, Thank you @Jakub! :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Jakub is indeed one way to solve it, but comes with an additional cost (azure function and logic app action to call the function).

Another way would be to return the XML from SQL as a base64 string. That way you use the base64ToString and xml functions in your Logic App.

Comment: Ok, now that i can live with. is there a way to use the base64ToString directly on the stored procedure? as in, in the same query so to speak?
Thank you @StevenVanEycken

Comment: OK so i have tried it and the base64tostring still becomes to long for the logic app to handle. it splitts the encoded xml just as much as the xml before it.

Comment: Hmm, I was not expecting that behavior. I'm wondering if the Data Operations Compose & Join might help you. I don't have time at the moment to try it out myself, but wil try to POC it this weekend.

Comment: Hi @stevenvaneycken, just wondering if you ever got around to that POC? :)

Answer (score 0):

The Azure Function solution worked great, I just coded it exactly how it was described.  The only hard part is getting the references working in azure.  Note: this works with any type of string data, I was using XML in my case.

Here's the code I used:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "System.Xml.Linq"
#r "System.Linq"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Linq;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"Webhook Combine Messages was triggered!");

    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    JArray array = JArray.Parse(jsonContent);

    List<string> list = array.Select(p => (string)p["XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B"]).ToList();
    foreach (var l in list)
        sb.Append(l);

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, sb.ToString());
}
```